# backbone model fetch async false doesn't work for firefox

Tags: backbone.js, asynchronous, synchronization, fetch

I have code as below, it works for chrome, but doesn't work for firefox, both latest version. does firefox doesn't support async false fetch of backbone ?

```
identity.fetch( { 
async: false, "xhrFields": { "withCredentials" : true }, 
 success : function ( model ) {
   dosomething();
 }

});
```

Comment: What exactly is your case in preferring synchronous requests?

Comment: such as for authentication phase, I want to do a login check before other modules get initialized (with requirejs).

Comment: then why don't you just pass your modules uninitialized through the module loader (requirejs) and initialize them as soon as the login is done?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone `Model.fetch` delegates to `jQuery.ajax` as stated in the [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync).

If you look in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), the part about **async** gives some hints about the correct usage of this option:

> [..] As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is
>   deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options
>   instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as
>   jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

So maybe it's a better option to go with the default and handle the response asychronously.

Comment: but not always that's convenient to put code into sucessfull call back?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `withCredentials` is not allowed with synchronous XMLHttpRequests (it raises an error at property-set-time, not at fetch-time).

Comment: yea, but I found it works for chrome, just firefox ignore this, probaly also ie11, not sure if this is the trend, to disgard this usage.